# Add an x:static command from code behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, material-design-in-xaml

I'm using WPF with MaterialDesign in XAML. I want to add a material design command from code behind.

If i was using XAML, I could do it like this:

```
Command="{x:Static materialDesign:Flipper.FlipCommand}"
```

but i want to do it in this context, using C# in the code behind:

```
flipButton.Command = "{ x: Static materialDesign:Flipper.FlipCommand}";
```

Comment: @Clemens yes, this worked. I tried this but my intellisense had bugged and was telling me it was wrong, but I ran it and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
flipButton.Command = MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.Flipper.FlipCommand;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
  flipButton.Command.Execute(@"{ x: Static materialDesign:Flipper.FlipCommand}");
```

`